# How to get the current login user name in my Script file inside my asp.net mvc

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a script file that makes a call to JSON API, and I need to send the current login username as part of the call. I tried the following :-

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var name = prompt("Please enter your packageid", "test");

        var fullurl = 'http://localhost:8080/jw/web/json/workflow/process/list?j_username=kermit&hash=9449B5ABCFA9AFDA36B801351ED3DF66&loginAs=' + HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name + 'packageId=' + name;
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: fullurl,
            dataType: "JSONP",
            success: function (result) {
//code goes here
```

But it will raise the following error:- **'HttpContext' is undefined**

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Your script is looking for a **Javascript** variable called `HttpContext` Your code should be

```
@HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name
```

in Razor

so the javascript becomes

```
 var fullurl = 'http://localhost:8080/jw/web/json/workflow/process/list?j_username=kermit&hash=9449B5ABCFA9AFDA36B801351ED3DF66&loginAs=@HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name&packageId=' + name;
```

You're also missing and `&` between the user name and packageId if you intended for them to be separate variables

**Edit**: based on your comment and this being inside of a js file (which I guess I missed in the OP)

Two options:

1. Is to hold the username inside a variable on the page calling the script file. Like this:

**Page**

```
<script>
var usrName = "@HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name";
</script>
```

**JS file**

```
....&loginAs='+ usrName + '&packageId=' + name;
```

Option Two is to not include the username at all and just get it from the Action. This is only an option if the page you're posting to is on the same app

Comment: you mean i should write the javascript inside the razor and not inside the Scripts folder.?.

Comment: @johnG, yes, that's what he means.

Comment: then there is no way to get the username from inside my .js file?

Comment: @Eonasdan but how i can pass the variable to the script,, i do not think it will work if i write <script>
var usrName = "@HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name";
</script>
in my razor view. can you post a complete code -if possible-

Comment: did you try it? because I do that all the time. As long as `var usrName` comes **first** - **before** the `.js` file it will work

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var name = prompt("Please enter your packageid", "test");

    var fullurl = 'http://localhost:8080/jw/web/json/workflow/process/list?j_username=kermit&hash=9449B5ABCFA9AFDA36B801351ED3DF66&loginAs=' + <%= HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name %> + 'packageId=' + name;
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: fullurl,
        dataType: "JSONP",
        success: function (result) {
```

the above code should work, on the javascript front you will not have access to HTTPContent object which is available only on the server, but putting them in a server code you should be able to access the same.

or you can have a hidden control with the value set from the server

```
<input type='hidden' id='uid' runat='server'>
```

server code would look like

```
uid.value = HTTPContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
```

Comment: i strongly suggest you relook at passing user id as a parameter, its not a suggested practice.

Comment: why but how i can integrate with other system instead ?, as i am sending a API request to return JSON from another application. so i have to send the username in my request.

Comment: at first please let me know the answer i gave works for you :) , second you should look at passing a token instead of exposing your userid, where the token should be generated on your server side.

Comment: thanks for your alert, but the web service i am integrating with expect a loginAs parameter to make the call, and it does not have a parameter for the token. baring in mind that i do not own the system i am integrating with.. any suggestions.?

Comment: is there a possibility for you to do an AJAX call to your server and your server gets the required info for you ? by that you would not be exposing your user id to the external world. using a WebRequest Class get WebResponse ?

Comment: to make things clearer. What i am doing is that i have an engine that have JSON APIs , and what i am currently doing is that i am building an asp.net mvc web application on-top-of the engine. and the user how will login to the asp.net web application should already been registered in the engine itself . second point is that to be able to get the json results from the engine i have to pass the username (loginas) so that the engine will check his validity ,, so i am not sure if i have another approach rather than exposing the username? best regards

Comment: well in your case i see your JSON API is http://localhost:8080/jw/web/json/workflow/process/list instead of calling it from the javascript, you will call this on your server via AJAX and all those APIs which do not need some sensitive information you can call it from the client using javascript

Comment: i understand you, but is there a demo explaining how i an call the API from the server and not using java script, in my asp.net mvc web applications?

Comment: I investigate your reply regarding using a token instead of passing the user name. now in my API call i am using  two parameters representing a master login credential for the API "j_username=kermit&hash=9449B5ABCFA9AFDA36B801351ED3DF66", so i think these two parameters are being used a tokens, OR i am missing something?

Comment: well this is atleast clear that you dont use loginas ... provides you first layer to security!

Comment: you mean i should not use LoginAS parameter and instead to hash its value?

Comment: you already did a good job of replacing the loginas with a hash! though there are many hash refactors, this atleast provides a first layer of security

Answer (score 1):

You can use just `User.Identity.Name` that's derived from `System.Web.WebPages.WebPageRenderingBase` (that means the code should be in a View-file). You can't access server-side code directly in script-files.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        var name = prompt("Please enter your packageid", "test");

        var fullurl = 'http://localhost:8080/jw/web/json/workflow/process/list?j_username=kermit&hash=9449B5ABCFA9AFDA36B801351ED3DF66&loginAs=@User.Identity.Name&packageId=' + name;
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: fullurl,
            dataType: "JSONP",
            success: function (result) {
//code goes here
```

Comment: this will raise "Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'User' is undefined" error.

Comment: as I suggest you need to make Razor render this into your javascript instead of asking javascript for it

Comment: Is the script in a view or a js-file?

Comment: in a separate script file under the Scripts folder, and i am just calling this script file in my razor.

Comment: @johnG Then you should put this code in a script-tag in say your _layout.cshtml file or other view-file.

Comment: sorry but this is not the best way to do this. moving the script file into the view will not allow for catching or easy reference later.

Comment: @Eonasdan Actually, *best way* depends on what the user needs, the complexity and maintainability, of course, but I would probably also do it in a similar way you have in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to set a javascript variable in your view (.cshtml) using razor and then use this in your script file (.js)

So in your view:

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
            var userName = '@HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name';            
</script>
```

and then your script file

```
   var fullurl = '....loginAs=' + userName  + 'packageId=' + name;
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, but what you mean by "to set a javascript variable in your view". i did not perform such thing before?

Comment: updated answer, Razor will not be interpreted by compiler in your .js files but it will in your .cshtml files.  Thus have the above script in your view and then use userName in your script

Answer (score 1):

```
    @User.Identity.Name
```

You can directly access user identity in script section by prefixing @

```
    @User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value
```

also a good option.

Answer (score 0):

> `var usrName = '<%=@HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name%>'`

Comment: Please, also provide a minimum explanation.

Comment: I think that is self explanatory:)

Comment: This answer is already provided by `Eonasdan`. He explains that this makes sense only in Razor (cshtml) only and how to pass it in a script outside of the view.