# How to get the system login information in TideSDK app using java script?

Tags: javascript, tidesdk

I have a desktop app built with TideSDK and java script.

The idea is to use system login to autologin ot the tideSDK app. I have tried following code snippet to get the system login username.

```
var WinNetwork = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Network");    //option 1 ref http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2968690/get-windows-username-with-javascript
console.log(WinNetwork);

var userName = @HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;   //option 2 ref http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12820172/how-to-get-the-current-login-user-name-in-my-script-file-inside-my-asp-net-mvc
```

In the option 1 it says ActiveXObject is not available.

In the option 2 it gives a parse error

```
SyntaxError: Parse error

Invoking masonry    /C:/ProgramData/TideSDK/modules/win32/ui/1.3.1%2Dbeta/ui.js:95
```

Option 1 may not work on anything other than IE.

What's wrong I am doing with option 2?

Is there any other way to get system user name from TideSDK app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The TideSDK provides it's own way to solve this.

just use

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var username = Ti.Platform.getUsername();
    console.log(username);
</script>
```

That will give the username of current system login