# Javascript "(index):87 Uncaught ReferenceError"

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

Please help,

My javascript code

```js
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        var url = "../Account/DeconnecterUtilisateur";
        var statutLogin = @HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
        $.getJSON(url, { usr: id }, function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        })
    });
</script>
```

is throwing this error message

> (index):87 Uncaught ReferenceError: patrice is not defined

And I can not get arround it.

My aim is to call within my account controller a method that will log off the user when ever that specifc view(that cobtains the script) is loaded.

Comment: In some place of your code as if not present here, reference of `patrice` is not found

Comment: Is it possible the name you send is patrice? maybe using this will help: var statutLogin = '@HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name';

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the current login user name in my Script file inside my asp.net mvc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12820172/how-to-get-the-current-login-user-name-in-my-script-file-inside-my-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: The quotes did settle the issue. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite to this:

```
var statutLogin = '@HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name';
```

Notice you need the apostrophes above since c# is generating js code before the script runs.

Comment: Glad to help. Now its your turn to be a good citizen and accept the best solution and possibly upvote good answers. :)

Comment: I'd be glad to but I even see how to achieve that(vote).
I probablly need some courses on Stackoveflow